# Functions which intersect asymptote $y=ax+b$ infinitely many times

Tags: calculus, functions, asymptotics, infinity

I'm looking for a case similar to $f(x)=\frac{sin(x)}{x},\ y=0$. But I need a function $f(x)$ with the asymptote $ax+b,\ a\ne 0$.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly but I think something like $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + ax+b$ is what you're looking for

Comment: @Slugger I hade the same idea at the same moment. Seems a pretty obvious example.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

sin(x)+x with asymptote y=x-something, adjust it with coefficients like a sin(x) + bx
[image: like sin(x)+x?]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't work... In this case the line is not an asymptote.